# Go GraphQL http request: how to get an array of items

Tags: go, graphql

How would one aquire an array of all my movies? using an empty interface results in a long string, using the movie struct i get the error `decoding response: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type graphql.graphResponse`

Any help would be appreciated as I am very new to Go.

```
type Movie struct {
    ID          string `json:"id"`
    Title       string `json:"title"`
    Genre       string `json:"genre"`
    ImgURL      string `json:"imgURL"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    ReleaseDate int    `json:"releaseDate"`
    Length      string `json:"length"`
    Likes       int    `json:"likes"`
    Comments    int    `json:"comments"`
}

func main() {
    graphqlClient := graphql.NewClient("http://localhost:8080/query")

    // make a request
    graphqlRequest := graphql.NewRequest(`
        {
            movies {
                id,
                title,
                genre,
                imgURL,
                description,
                releaseDate,
                length,
                likes,
                comments,
            }
        }
    `)

    // run it and capture the response
    var graphqlResponse []Movie
    err := graphqlClient.Run(context.Background(), graphqlRequest, &graphqlResponse)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(graphqlResponse)
}
```

Comment: what is actual json response?

Comment: response is ``` map[movies:[map[comments:50 description:Horror genre: id:1 imgURL:random description length:2h 20m likes:50 releaseDate:10 title:The conjuring 2] map[comments:0 description:Horror genre: id:2 imgURL:random description length:2h 20m likes:0 releaseDate:10 title:The conjuring 3]]] ```

Comment: it is not json. Add debug logging `graphqlClient.Log = func(s string) { log.Println(s) }` and add response json to the question.